# Connect several puppet masters to one puppetdb

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppetdb

I have installed a puppetdb on one of my puppetmaster and it works. But I'm not able to connect a second one to the puppet master.

The command "puppet agent -t" works on my 2nd master.

Each master deals with their own nodes (their is no LB).

Here is the puppetserver.log when I run the puppet agent command :

```
2017-06-22 15:48:21,255 ERROR [qtp1178717687-64] [c.p.h.c.i.PersistentSyncHttpClient] Error executing http request
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.checkThrown(Handshaker.java:1431) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.checkTaskThrown(SSLEngineImpl.java:535) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.writeAppRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1214) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.wrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:1186) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:469) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doWrap(SSLIOSession.java:263) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:303) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:507) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:122) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:164) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:339) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:317) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:278) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:590) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1728) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:304) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:919) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:916) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1369) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doRunTask(SSLIOSession.java:281) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:351) ~[puppet-server-release.jar:na]
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:281) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
```

I have the default configuration in the jetty.ini :

```
[jetty]
# IP address or hostname to listen for clear-text HTTP. To avoid resolution
# issues, IP addresses are recommended over hostnames.
# Default is `localhost`.
# host = <host>

# Port to listen on for clear-text HTTP.
port = 8080


# The following are SSL specific settings. They can be configured
# automatically with the tool `puppetdb ssl-setup`, which is normally
# ran during package installation.

# IP address to listen on for HTTPS connections. Hostnames can also be used
# but are not recommended to avoid DNS resolution issues. To listen on all
# interfaces, use `0.0.0.0`.
ssl-host = 0.0.0.0

# The port to listen on for HTTPS connections
ssl-port = 8081

# Private key path
ssl-key = /etc/puppetdb/ssl/private.pem

# Public certificate path
ssl-cert = /etc/puppetdb/ssl/public.pem

# Certificate authority path
ssl-ca-cert = /etc/puppetdb/ssl/ca.pem
```

Here is my puppetdb.conf on my 2nd master :

```
[main]
server_urls = https://puppetmaster01.domain.com:8081
```

When I launched the puppetdb ssl-setup the 1st time, it said it copied puppetmaster ssl (ca, private and public) from /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl. So I tried to copy those from my master02 and add it to the 3 files specify in the jetty, but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT :** I found a doc which tells I have to use CA cert. So I generated a CA cert with that command :

```
puppet cert generate puppetmaster01.domain.com --allow-dns-alt-names  --dns_alt_names=puppetmaster.domain.com,puppetmaster01.domain.com,puppetmaster02.domain.com
```

After I used this one to setup ssl for puppetdb :

```
puppetdb ssl-setup -f
```

1st problem : My master works, I copied the ssl/certs/ca.pem on my nodes in ssl/certs, they are able to generate a new SSL but my master never received it.

2nd problem : I copied all the SSL directory from my 1st master to the 2nd, I renamed SSL files with the good name but when I launch my puppet agent -t I get that :

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: puppetmaster01.domain.com(IP_MASTER_02) access to /puppet/v3/catalog/puppetmaster02.domain.com [find] authenticated  at :68
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Error 403 on SERVER: Forbidden request: puppetmaster01.domain.com(172.27.15.24) access to /puppet/v3/report/puppetmaster02.domain.com [save] authenticated  at :78
```

It's like it tries to get information for master01 instead of 02...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to use the CA, you just have to take the repo puppet/ssl/ca and put it on your other servers and regenerate the SSL.

So on the 1st master you use :
puppet cert generate puppetmaster01.domain.com --allow-dns-alt-names  --dns_alt_names=puppetmaster.domain.com,puppetmaster01.domain.com,puppetmaster02.domain.com

Copy all the puppet/ssl/ca on your 2nd master and regenerate the ssl for this one :
puppet cert generate puppetmaster02.domain.com